# Get weeks from start and end date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am building a timetable function, for that I have to insert the data week wise in an collection.

So I'm creating a array which will contain the weeks from start_date to end_date.

**1st Push in an array:** start_date = Declared date (if declared date is Sunday, then it consider the date of coming Monday); end_date = date on Saturday

**2nd till nth Push in an array:** start_date = date on Monday; end_date = date on Saturday or declared end date if its within the week

```
var start = new Date("09/30/2016");
var end = new Date("11/2/2016");

var count = 0;
var sDate;
var eDate;
var dateArr = [];

while(start <= end){
    if (start.getDay() == 0){
        count = 0;
    }else {
        if(count == 0){
            sDate = start;
            count = 1
        }else {
            count = 1;
        }

        if(start.getDay() == 6 || start == end){
            count = 1
            eDate = start;
        }else {
            count = 1;
        }

        if(sDate && eDate){
            sDate = new Date(sDate)
            eDate = new Date(eDate)
            dateArr.push({'startDate': sDate, 'endDate': eDate});
            sDate = undefined;
            eDate = undefined;
        }
    }

    var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    start = new Date(newDate);
}
```

But the result Im getting is this

```
[{
    'startDate':Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Tue Oct 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Tue Oct 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Tue Oct 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Tue Oct 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
}]
```

**Edit:**

**Expected Result:**

```
[{
    'startDate':Fri Sep 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Mon Oct 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Mon Oct 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Mon Oct 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Mon Oct 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
    'endDate':Sat Oct 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
},
{
    'startDate':Mon Oct 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
    'endDate':Wed Nov 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
}]
```

Comment: have a look at [momentsjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @miraculixx Before pushing in the array the start date if console.log displays Monday.
I have tried using moments.js too. start date still displays as next date

Comment: What result do you need (the number of weeks between the dates)?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I need all the week's start date and end date between the given dates in an array of an object

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I have added my expected result in the Question

Comment: Note that the result of `new Date("09/30/2016")` is implementation dependent and may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. I fixed some logical and obj reference errors.

```
var start = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30, 0, 0, 0));
var end = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 11, 02, 0, 0, 0));
var sDate;
var eDate;
var dateArr = [];

while(start <= end){
  if (start.getDay() == 1 || (dateArr.length == 0 && !sDate)){
    sDate = new Date(start.getTime());
  }

  if ((sDate && start.getDay() == 0) || start.getTime() == end.getTime()){
        eDate = new Date(start.getTime());
  }

  if(sDate && eDate){
    dateArr.push({'startDate': sDate, 'endDate': eDate});
    sDate = undefined;
    eDate = undefined;
  }

    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(dateArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c58zde4b/6/

The displayed date may vary due to your local timezone settings.

Comment: In this the first object in array is Monday but in my expected result its Friday. All the other Objects are getting start date as Sunday. Plus the number of objects are 1 less

Comment: Please see updated answer. 
- Note: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.
- If dates don't match by a small offset make you are looking at the right timezone.

Comment: I have made some changes to your answer which has worked for me, Just review it. I'll mark it as Answer

Comment: I can't see your changes in my URL. Everytime you save new changes into jsfiddle a new URL is created. 

Thank you for choosing my answer :)

Comment: An answer should explain the OP's issue and how your code fixes it. Just posting code may help the OP, but it's not helpful to other users who may have the same issue (whatever that was). In particular, what is the point of using *Date.UTC*?

Comment: @SergeyGurevich your jsfiddle example is displaying same values for the startDate and endDate for the first element!! Once check it